# How could I find the sum of this infinite series by hand?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(7n+32)3^n}{n(n+2)4^n}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n$?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This has become a hot question so I'd like to remind people that this homework/book question is not well researched - I'm not saying downvote, just don't upvote.

Comment: You have quite an imaginative math tutor or lecturer!

Answer (score 10):

HINT

Notice, $$\frac{(7n+32)3^n}{n(n+2)4^n}=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\frac{(7n+32)}{n(n+2)}=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\left(\frac{16}{n}-\frac{9}{n+2}\right)$$

Comment: That's really rockin'!

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^{n+2}}{n+2} = -\log(1-z)-z-\frac{z^2}{2}\tag{1}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(-\log(1-z)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n+2}\right)\tag{2}$$
give:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{7n+32}{n(n+2)}\,z^n = \frac{18 z+9 z^2+18 \log(1-z)-32 z^2 \log(1-z)}{2 z^2}.\tag{3} $$
Now just replace $z$ with $\frac{3}{4}$ to see the $\log$-part vanishing and the sum being $\displaystyle\color{red}{\frac{33}{2}}$.

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Let the $n(\ge1)$th term  $T_n=\dfrac{(7n+32)3^n}{n(n+2)4^n}=A\dfrac{\left(\dfrac34\right)^n}n+B\dfrac{\left(\dfrac34\right)^{n+2}}{n+2}$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants

$\implies\dfrac{(7n+32)}{n(n+2)}=\dfrac An+ \dfrac{B\left(\dfrac34\right)^2}{n+2}$

$\implies7n+32=A(n+2)+\dfrac{9Bn}{16}$

Comparing the constants, $32=2A\iff A=16$

Comparing the coefficients of $n, 7=A+\dfrac{9B}{16}\iff B=\dfrac{16(7-A)}9=\cdots=-16$

$\implies T_n=16\cdot\dfrac{\left(\dfrac34\right)^n}n-16\cdot\dfrac{\left(\dfrac34\right)^{n+2}}{n+2}=16\left(u_n-u_{n+2}\right)$ 
where $u_m=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac34\right)^m}m$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ clearly [telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to $16(u_1+u_2)=?$

Comment: nice answer ........+1